# Multi store views(3) and same CartController, why in one of them getting "Please specify the product required option(s)."

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, addtocart

I have added a same simple product with custom options in all three views and getting

> Please specify the product required option(s).

upon adding to cart in one of them. What could be the reason as all are using same controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in addtocart.phtml in its template ;)

The solution was changing

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: @versedi I tried to mark it but it did not let me (18 hours later I'll try again)

Comment: @7ochem I completed the solution ;)